# Insert SQL NULL when no ComboBox value is selected

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, combobox, null

StudeStude> Scenario - C# Application + SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table Currency with the following structure

```
currencyID - int - NOT NULL - Primary Key - IS Identity (**True**)

currency - VARCHAR(50) - NOT NULL
```

1. Now , this currencyID is a foreign key in another table Student_Payment_Details.
2. The currency table is hosted in a ComboBox Control.
3. **I need a way to insert NULL (or nothing) in case no currency option is selected**. 
   (e.g selectedIndex = -1)

> *Been reading articles stating that it's against all SQL rules to insert a NULL for a foriegn key while its bound to a primary NOT NULL key in the master table*

**So, guys, i need your suggestions for a workaround. Thank you in advance.**

- Here's a trimmed version of my stored procedure

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStudentPaymentDetails]

  ```
      -- PARAMETERS
      **** blah blah ***
      @currencyID int = null,
      @studentFees varchar(100) = null,
      **** blah blah ***
  AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
              -- Add Student Details
              INSERT INTO Student_Payment_Details(****,currencyID,studentFees,****) values(****,@currencyID,@studentFees,****);
              SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();    
  END
  ```

Comment: see my answer below, FK does not prevent you to store a NULL, only limit is that if it's not null has to exists on your other table. this also depends on how you created the student_payment_details table of course, you should allow nulls in that CurrencyId column even if you added FK constraint.

Comment: FYI : I solved the problem by adding these lines before INSERTION to my stored procedure ( IF @currencyID = 0 SET @currencyID=NULL;  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to insert a record with `CurrencyID == NULL` in the table `Student_Payment_Details` even if it's a FK to the Currency table.

what is not possible is to insert a record with PK NULL in the currency table but this is not your case.

Comment: Please let me elaborate a little further. The code for insertion is contained in a stored procedure. I can insert NULL via executing it in the SQL Management Studio , but passing through VS raises exceptions (FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ERROR)

Comment: show more details of your tables and the stored procedure then.

Comment: +1 it should be possible to do this as the OP business requirement is asking for it. If the stored procedure is blocking something that is required by the user, then the stored procedure is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a 'NONE' currency record in your table and use that ID.

Comment: mmm, I would not like this option, because that is not a valid real Currency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take some distance from it and I see 2 options :

- Use a fake value (like the none from the other answer).
- Don't insert line at all and consider it as no option selected.